# Bash: close if pipe IO is idle

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

How can I close a program if a pipe stream is idle for a period of time?

Say for instance:

`someprogram | closeidlepipe -t 500 | otherprogram`

Is there some program `closeidlepipe` that can close if idle for a period (`-t 500`)?

`timeout` can close after a period, but not with the "idle" distinction.

UPDATE

It is important to note that `someprogram` outputs an endless stream of binary data. The data may contain the null character `\0` and should be piped verbatim.

Comment: man 3 select; should be an hour's worth of coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the general form of the heart of a program that does this.

```
while(1) {
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.m_sec = 0;
    tv.m_usec = 500000;
    int marker = 1;
    select(1, &marker, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    if (marker == 0) exit(1);
    char buf[8192];
    int n = read(0, buf, 8192);
    if (n < 0) exit(2);
    char *b = buf;
    while (n)
    {
        int l = write(1, b, n);
        if (l <= 0) exit(3);
        b += l;
        n -= l;
     }
}
```

Comment: Won't this block on the read if less than 8192 bytes are available?

Comment: Only if the file descriptor is set to non-blocking

Comment: On the contrary I have test cases for this working on blocking handles. read() only blocks if zero bytes are available immediately.

Comment: Although this is not a bash solution, this would work *in* a bash environment. Also I adore C/C++. I'm accepting

Answer (score 1):

The builtin `read` has a timeout option `-t`.

```
someprogram |
  while :; do
    IFS= read -d'' -r -t 500 line
    res=$?
    if [[ $res -eq 0 || )); then
      # Normal read up to delimiter
      printf '%s\0' "$line"
    else
      # Either read timed out without reading another null
      # byte, or there was some other failure meaning we
      # should break. In neither case did we read a trailing null byte
      # that read discarded.
      [[ -n $line ]] && printf '%s' "$line"
      break
    fi
  done | 
  otherprogram
```

If `read` times out after 500 seconds, the `while` loop will exit and the middle part of the pipeline closes. `someprogram` will receive a `SIGCHLD` signal the next time it tries to write to its end of that pipe, allowing it to exit.

Comment: If i didn't want to read line by line but rather as much as possible? Should I use `-n 4096` or something similar? It is supposed to be an endless stream for my use case

Comment: Also will printf work correctly for binary data, as in allow null (0x00) in the string without stopping?

Comment: That raises a better point, which is that `read` is going to discard whatever delimiter it uses to define a line. You'd have to write the delimiter out as well, *if*  `read` actually timed out. The more I think about this, the less I think this is a good idea.